# Ada rendezvouz mutual synchronization

Tags: task, synchronization, ada

So i've got code like this:

```
task body Task1Type is
begin
    Put_Line("Task1 Part1");
    Task2.Part1Ready;
    accept Part1Ready;
    Put_Line("Task1 Part2");
end;

task body Task2Type is
begin
    Put_Line("Task2 Part1");
    Task1.Part1Ready;
    accept Part1Ready;
    Put_Line("Task2 Part2");
end;
```

My logic tells me that part2 in every task must run after both tasks completed task1. But it doesn't. Where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `Task1` calls `Task2.Part1Ready`, it blocks until `Task2` issues `accept Part1Ready`. Likewise, when `Task2` calls `Task1.Part1Ready`, it blocks until `Task1` issues `accept Part1Ready`.

This is known as a ‘deadly embrace', and means that neither task can proceed. One way round this is to use a protected object, perhaps like this:

```
protected Readiness is
   procedure Task_1_Ready;
   entry Wait_Until_Task_1_Ready;

   procedure Task_2_Ready;
   entry Wait_Until_Task_2_Ready;
private
   Task_1_Is_Ready : Boolean := False;
   Task_2_Is_Ready : Boolean := False;
end Readiness;

protected body Readiness is
   procedure Task_1_Ready is
   begin
      Task_1_Is_Ready := True;
   end Task_1_Ready;

   entry Wait_Until_Task_1_Ready when Task_1_Is_Ready is
   begin
      null;
   end Wait_Until_Task_1_Ready;

   procedure Task_2_Ready is
   begin
      Task_2_Is_Ready := True;
   end Task_2_Ready;

   entry Wait_Until_Task_2_Ready when Task_2_Is_Ready is
   begin
      null;
   end Wait_Until_Task_2_Ready;
end Readiness;
```

Then get rid of the `Part1Ready` task entries, replacing

```
task body Task1Type is begin
   Put_Line("Task1 Part1");
   Task2.Part1Ready;
   accept Part1Ready;
   Put_Line("Task1 Part2”);
end;
```

with

```
task body Task1Type is begin
   Put_Line("Task1 Part1");
   Readiness.Task_1_Ready;
   Readiness.Wait_Until_Task_2_Ready;
   Put_Line("Task1 Part2”);
end;
```

and vice-versa in `Task2Type`.